# How add Kaltura Player in iOS application

Tags: ios, objective-c, kaltura

I try to add Kaltura Player in my iOS application.
I already read examples in this documentation (http://knowledge.kaltura.com/kaltura-player-sdk-ios) but, for me, they don't work, bcs `KPViewController` haven't method `initWithURL`.
So, I do this in `viewDidAppear`method

```
if ( self.KPlayer == nil ) 
{
    self.KPlayer = [[KPViewController alloc] init];
    [self.KPlayer.player setContentURL:fileURL];
    [self.KPlayer.player play];
    [self presentViewController:self.KPlayer animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

But video not displayed and in logs I got a message:

```
::Error:: -[KPViewController viewDidAppear:] (line:168) 
Delegate MUST be set and respond to selector -getInitialKIframeUrl
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you're importing KPViewController, because it has a custom initializer initWithURL:. Also KPViewController does not have any player property (not a public one at least). The player (id<KPlayer>) is lazily created by the KPlayerController (which is also not a public property of KPViewController). So your implementation sounds broken to me :-) (sorry to say that :-)). Need to see more to be able to answer correctly.

Answer (score 1):

There are updates in Kaltura SDK for iOS and Android which they havent changed/updated in their documentation so far. :

According to old SDK there was method initWithUrl in KPViewController and 
you could play the video using :

```
NSString *videoUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://cdnapisec.kaltura.com/p/243342/sp/24334200/embedIframeJs/uiconf_id/12905712/partner_id/1988382?iframeembed=true&entry_id=%@",entryId];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:videoUrl];

    self.player = [[KPViewController alloc] initWithURL:url];
    self.player.view.frame = [self.viewVideo bounds];
    [self.player loadPlayerIntoViewController:self];
    [self.viewVideo addSubview:self.player.view];
```

but according to new SDK and Demo reference App : https://github.com/kaltura/IOSReferenceApp

```
install the SDK using pod :
1) on terminal,go to the Project Directory and run -> pod init
2) open the Podfile and copy and paste
 pod 'player-sdk-native-ios', '~> 1.1' 
before this line : target 'KalturaVideo_ObjC' do
close and save the file
3) pod install
4) close your current XCode project and open your ProjectName.xcworkspace file
```

there is - (void)drawPlayer method in MediaInfoViewController_iPhone.m which adds KPViewController* playerViewController to the ViewController

just in case if you are unable to play the video using the demo app, then call [self playButtonPressed]; at the end of drawPlayer method, which will directly play the video , the playButtonPressed method has the implementation to play videos.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're importing KPViewController, because it has a custom initializer initWithURL:. Also KPViewController does not have any player property (not a public one at least). The player (id) is lazily created by the KPlayerController (which is also not a public property of KPViewController). So your implementation sounds broken to me :-) (sorry to say that :-)). Need to see more to be able to answer correctly.